# Button Vertical Text

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<button class="btn" id="servicos">b</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn{
line-height: normal;
display:inline;
position:relative;
border: 0;
margin:0;
width:6%;
height:95%;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000000;
text-align:center;
font-size: 18px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

My problem is that since the button width and height are in % the text inside the button in centered vertically, is there any way the text could be on top?

Comment: `line-height` may help you, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose "b" into span

```
<button class="btn" id="servicos"><span>b</span></button>
<style>
.btn{
line-height: normal;
color:white;
display:inline;
position:relative;
border: 0;
margin:0;
width:6%;
height:95%;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000000;
text-align:center;
font-size: 18px;
vertical-align:top;
}
.btn span{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, but only if you place an extra element inside the button with certain css properties.

I have an example on JSfiddle.

```
.btn #buttontext
{
position: relative;
top: -6px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wSVJK/